# Importing a css stylesheet in a module

Tags: angular, sass, ngx-bootstrap

I'm publishing a module on NPM. In that module I have several components, which use ngx-bootstrap/datepicker. That requires a certain stylesheet imported out of node_modules.

Now the problem is: I can't find a way to import that stylesheet for that module.

There are two solutions I have found:

1. Import the stylesheet in the global styles.css of the application (or in angular-cli.json)
2. Import the stylesheet in every component of my module

The problems are:
I would like to avoid the first solution, since I would like my module to work out of the box when imported. 
The second solution does not work, I think it has something to do with the scope. Even if it would work, it's a dirty solution, since I have to import the file in every component where I need it.

Does anyone have a solution for that problem?

Comment: how do you bundle your module, webpack with css loader is a good option to work without any other configuration

Comment: Im bundling it with a library called angular2-library (yeoman generator). That lib creates the basic structure of the library and a gulp file where I can bundle everything with

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular CLI, this is as simple as including one line in your component.css file and this must work.

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

Importing styles into module or components forces style emulation and scoping of styles, which affects app performance and makes hard to override your styles.

If you provide additional styles users of your lib should include your css the same way as they include bootstrap.css